# Non power of two textures and memory consumption optimization

Tags: optimization, memory-management, xna, textures

I read somewhere that XNA framework upscales a texture to nearest power of two size and then sends that to VRAM, which, provided it's how it really works, might be not efficient when loading many small (in my case 150×150) textures, which essentially waste memory with unused texture data resulting from upscaling.

So is there some automatic optimization, or should I make my own implementation of it, like loading all textures, figuring out where the "upscaled" space is big enough to hold some other texture and place it there, remembering sprite positions, thus using one texture instead of two (or more)?

It isn't always handy to do this manually for each texture (placing many small sprites in a single texture), because it's hard to work with later (essentially it becomes less human-oriented), and not always a sprite will be needed in some level of a game, so it would be better if sprites were in a different composition, so it should be done automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are tools available to create what are known as "sprite sheets" or "texture atlases". [This XNA sample](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/sprite_sheet) does this for you as part of a content pipeline extension.

Note that the padding of textures only happens on devices that do not support non-power-of-two textures. Windows Phone, for example. Modern GPUs won't waste the RAM. However this is still a useful optimisation to allow you to merge batches of sprites (see [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9277/optimizing-an-xna-2d-game) for details).